# Cascade delete not working SQLite with 1:1 relationship

Tags: sqlite, cascading-deletes

I'm trying to set up a 1:1 relationship between two tables `Places` and `People`. A person has a home, and when that person is deleted the home should also be deleted. Other tables also use the `Places` table, so there is no column in the `Places` table that refers to the `People` table.

To try and achieve this, I've set the `People` table up so that when a row is deleted, there is a cascade delete on the foreign key pointing at the `Places` table row is also deleted.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "People" (
    "Id" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_People" PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "HomeId" TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_People_Places_HomeId" FOREIGN KEY ("HomeId") REFERENCES "Places" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

However, when I actually tried this, the row in the `Places` table still existed. Is there any way to fix this?

---

Fully runnable example

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Places" (
    "Id" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Places" PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "People" (
    "Id" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_People" PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "HomeId" TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_People_Places_HomeId" FOREIGN KEY ("HomeId") REFERENCES "Places" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);

DELETE FROM Places;
DELETE FROM People;

INSERT INTO "Places" ("Id", "Name") VALUES ("6f81fa78-2820-48e1-a0a7-b0b71aa38262", "Castle");
INSERT INTO "People" ("Id", "HomeId", "Name") VALUES ("ccb079ce-b477-47cf-adba-9fdac6a41718", "6f81fa78-2820-48e1-a0a7-b0b71aa38262", "Fiona");

-- Should delete both the person and the place, but does not
DELETE FROM "People" WHERE "Id" = "ccb079ce-b477-47cf-adba-9fdac6a41718";

SELECT pl.Name "Place Name",
         po.Name "Person Name"
FROM Places pl
LEFT JOIN People po USING(Name)
UNION ALL
SELECT pl.Name,
         po.Name
FROM People po
LEFT JOIN Places pl USING(Name)
WHERE pl.Name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`"ON DELETE CASCADE"`](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) action for the foreign key that you defined in the table `People` for the column `HomeId` which references the column `Id` of the table `Places` means that:

> whenever you delete a row in the table `Places` (which is the parent
> table in this relationship) all rows in the table `People` that hold a
> reference to the deleted row will also be deleted.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=eb878fc1210fd26c3f91cc4dff1a61cc).

In your case you are deleting a row in the table `People` and this does not affect at all the table `Places`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't realise db<>fiddle was a thing, but will use it in the future. So given that the `People` table is the child table, (I thought it was the other way round originally), there is no way to do this from the `People` table?

Comment: @Dan this can be done with triggers: https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html and https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger/ but it does not actually make sense. You mention in your question that the relationship is 1:1 Does this mean that for each place there is only 1 person? If so, when you insert a row in  in Places you should also insert 1 and only 1 row in People and make sure that no other row in People will be related to that row in Places (with triggers again). You could avoid this complicated relationship if you had only 1 table that would include the columns of both tables.